# I need help reading data from a file for my c code and i cant seem to figure out the error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START_YEAR 1760
#define END_YEAR 2015
#define NUM_YEARS (END_YEAR - START_YEAR + 1)
#define NUM_MONTHS 12

int main() {
     float LandAvg[NUM_YEARS][NUM_MONTHS];
     float Uncertainty[NUM_YEARS][NUM_MONTHS];

     FILE *file = fopen("Untitleddocument.txt", "r");
     if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read data from file
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_YEARS; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_MONTHS; ++j) {
            int year, month, day;
            if (fscanf(file, "%d-%d-%d %f %f", &year, &month, &day, &LandAvg[i][j], &Uncertainty[i][j]) != 5) {
                printf("Error reading data for year %d, month %d.\n", START_YEAR + i, j + 1);
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    // Display the entered data for verification
    printf("Data read from file:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_YEARS; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_MONTHS; ++j) {
            printf("%d-%02d-%02d %.3f %.3f\n", START_YEAR + i, j + 1, 1, 
                   LandAvg[i][j], Uncertainty[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

file data :

```
1760-01-01 -0.811 4.567
1760-02-01 2.436 3.535
1760-03-01 1.864 4.666
1760-04-01 7.436 2.669
1760-05-01 10.661 1.857
1760-06-01 11.945 2.140
1760-07-01 12.887 2.567
1760-08-01 13.917 2.789
1760-09-01 11.197 3.865
1760-10-01 6.701 3.422
1760-11-01 5.436 2.348
1760-12-01 2.553 2.642
```

my code error:

> Error reading data for year 1760, month 1.

also I'm coding on geany

My code is supposed to read the file and print the data from the file, I've added the code and whats on the file I'm expecting it to print the data of the file when i run the code but i keep getting an error that it failed to read file, I've tried changing the format checking file path but i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: When new programmers have issues reading data from a file, by far the most common problem is that the file is not actually open. That is usually one of two things: 1) file permissions issue; 2) file is not in the current working directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste both the code and file contents *as text* into your question. Then also please tell us the exact output you get from your program. Also please tell us *how* you run the program.

Comment: There are two possible errors your code can print. Which one is it?

Comment: The example file you show doesn't have enough data to satisfy the loops. Make sure you disambiguate between `EOF` and failed `fscanf`, by capturing its return value and making that distinction.

Comment: sorry guys first time posting i think I've fixed it so the code should be posted so it can be copy pasted and the file data

Comment: Are you really trying to open and read from `"Untitleddocument.txt"`? That seems like a really strange name for a data file. (note: I voted to reopen --- one more required)

Comment: ye sorry im just trying to figure our the read file stuff that's why I haven't renamed the file to something better

Comment: How many parameters were parsed in `fscanf`? It seems to fail for the very first line. Did any number match at all?

Comment: Not sure if a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) messes up `fscanf()` but try `int dummy = fgetc(file); dummy = fgetc(file);` just after opening the file (and ignore the first two bytes of the file) to see it that is the issue. Also try and create files without BOMs (your file does not need characters outside the standard ASCII range).

Comment: Does your input file have encoding related bytes in the beginning? For example, some editors might include BOM bytes (byte-order mark) to the UTF-8 encoded files. `fscanf` function might not understand those and fail to match the first integer.

Comment: so i tried what you wrote pmg and it gave me the error The system cannot execute the specified program. and honestly idrk if my file includes BOMs I was just given data on an excel sheet

Comment: Somewhere in time your program will read all data from the file, so `fscanf` will not return 5. Then your program does what? It prints a message and returns `1`. And it does! And you wrote it this way, and seems to be surprised by it.

Comment: thanks for the help guys it was the BOM messing it up got it to work so imma close this

Comment: So... me and user694733 were right after all! :-)